# Como trabalhar com sistemas espelhados?

Tags: php, xml, servidor, metodologia, hospedagem

Eu gostaria de saber qual seria a lógica para se trabalhar em um sistema web aonde eu teria um site principal e distribuiria ***sites*** para os franqueados em seus domínios.

Todo o processo de checkout deve ser feito no site do franqueado mas as informações seriam alimentadas no banco de dados do site principal.

- Domínios teriam que estar no mesmo servidor para isso seja possível?
- Sistema desse tipo existe ou precisa ser criado?
- É possível trabalhar diversas lojas em um único banco de dados?
- Qual é o grau de complexidade de um sistema desse tipo?
- Como poderiam os produtos do banco alimentar o site da franquia? Via
  XML?

As respostas podem ser curtas desde que me dê uma ideia de onde começar. Acho que isso se compara mais ou menos a Polishop. Alguém me ajuda?

Comment: Da pra escrever um livro com esta pergunta. Restrinja mais ela.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - Domínios teriam que estar no mesmo servidor para isso seja possível?

Não necessariamente. Você poderia apenas criar uma entrada CNAME no domínio apontando para o seu servidor. Quando a página fosse carregada você poderia identificar o domínio de onde o request veio, localizar o cliente que é dono desse domínio e carregar carregar as informações associadas.

> - Sistema desse tipo existe ou precisa ser criado?

Eu não conheço nenhum do tipo que seja aberto ou esteja à venda. É bem provável que exista.

> - É possível trabalhar diversas lojas em um único banco de dados?

É sim. Acredito até que diminuiria a complexidade do sistema. Você só precisaria do ID do cliente nessas tabelas para associar as informações.

> - Qual é o grau de complexidade de um sistema desse tipo?

Seria um sistema ligeiramente complexo mas nada de outro mundo.

> - Como poderiam os produtos do banco alimentar o site da franquia? Via XML?

Se você usar essa técnica do mesmo sistema para todos tudo viria diretamente do banco central.

Comment: downvote sem nenhum comentário?